# Which Desktop Client can be connect to MongoDB 2

Tags: mongodb

Current version Mongo DB GUI tools cannot be connect to **MongoDB 2.x** in 2021 years.

Dose have some tools can connected? (Windows And Linux).

Or can be installed at server and use web to connecting.

#### Not working screenshoot List

1. Studio 3T 2021.10.1

[image]

2. Compass 1.29.6

[image]

Comment: https://robomongo.org/ Robo3T?

Comment: try use Navicat Premium.

Comment: Robo 3T 8.5 download link is unavailable. Navicat Premunum is start from 3.0

Comment: Why do you run a far outdated release of MongoDB?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/mongodb-js/compass/releases it goes back to version 0.0.1, released in 2015.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't want to, but the company is afraid of upgrading. Several years have passed.

Comment: Is your company aware that it is a fairly high risk to run outdated and unsupported software?

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit Of course don't have this awareness. Only know that upgrading from 2 to 5 requires a lot of changes, Fear of breaking down by making changes. Because database, php, framework also cannot upgrade because this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the "rock mongo" based on PHP 5.

Available to connect mongo 2 last version is 1.1.7

Github source is [@iwind/rockmongo](https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo)

I make that installers cache at: [rockmongo-v1.1.7.zip](https://oss.bklab.cn/d/a/rockmongo-v1.1.7.zip)

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB Compass, sometimes shortened to Compass, you can access most of the features the MongoDB database engine offers through an intuitive visual display. You can glance through databases, collections and individual documents, interactively create queries, manipulate existing documents, and design aggregation pipelines through a dedicated interface.[Download here](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/compass)